# Migrate projects ioncube 9 to ioncube 10.2

Tags: php, project, migrate, ioncube

How can
migrate projects from version 9 to version 10
Should I pass project 1 x 1 or can I import them into version 10 once I have installed it?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special that you need to do immediately. Assuming you use the GUI, note however that the Encoder version used by the GUI will be the same if possible, so if your project is set to use the current Encoder, i.e. 9, when you open the project in version 10 it will then use the legacy Encoder, i.e. still 9, and not 10. (recall that Encoder comes with 3 versions, the current plus legacy and obsolete). This is so that if you encode your project after upgrading, you get the benefit of any new GUI features but it will produce files the same as before. If you want to switch to encoding with the version 10 Encoder, change the Encoder version on the source files tab of project settings. I'd recommend contacting ionCube support if you need more assistance.